Error con el ESP32
Estoy programando un minero de bitcoin con el ESP32, en un nucleo estoy minando y con el otro quiero enviar estadisticas sobre el minero a un servidor a traves de MQTT el proble es que cuando intento utilizar el otro nucleo para conectarme con el servidor MQTT me arroja el siguiente error:
E (6448) task_wdt:  - IDLE0 (CPU 0)
E (6448) task_wdt: Tasks currently running:
E (6448) task_wdt: CPU 0: sendData
E (6448) task_wdt: CPU 1: loopTask
E (6448) task_wdt: Aborting.
abort() was called at PC 0x400dc2d7 on core 0

Backtrace: 0x4008c454:0x3ffbe170 0x4008c685:0x3ffbe190 0x400dc2d7:0x3ffbe1b0 0x40084791:0x3ffbe1d0 0x400826ed:0x3fffc8f0 0x400d5091:0x3fffc910 0x400d3de6:0x3fffc950 0x400d3e46:0x3fffc970 0x40088b9d:0x3fffc990

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:8896
load:0x40080400,len:5828
entry 0x400806ac
[W][WiFiGeneric.cpp:596] setTxPower(): Neither AP or STA has been started
WiFi Setup
Conectando a SSID: WiFi_Fibertel_36x_2.4GHz[D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:337] _eventCallback(): Event: 0 - WIFI_READY
[D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:337] _eventCallback(): Event: 2 - STA_START
.[D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:337] _eventCallback(): Event: 4 - STA_CONNECTED
[D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:337] _eventCallback(): Event: 7 - STA_GOT_IP
[D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:381] _eventCallback(): STA IP: 192.168.1.52, MASK: 255.255.255.0, GW: 192.168.1.1```
Que puedo hacer ya intente de todo, intente dejar el loop principal vacio para que solo trabaje el core 0 y me sigue dando el mismo error


Si publicaras el código podría probarlo en mi ESP32. Lástima.

En realidad si lo tengo publicado en Github link: https://github.com/joaquinStrada/ESP32-MIner-FIrmware/tree/main

Probaste que el broker es accesible??? Porque simplemente puedes tener un problema de red (de routeo o firewall). Además, el código debe ir en la pregunta, y debe ser un [MCVE] con énfasis en lo de "MINIMO"

Ha mira no probe eso capaz ese sea el problema!!!!

El código MQTT depende del acceso a un servidor minero (que no tengo). ¿Probastes el código MQTT por si solo antes de agregar el minero?

Aclaración: trabajo MQTT con microPython, por lo que no tengo mayor experiencia con C++. Tengo algunos controladores corriendo que envían mensajes mqtt cada minuto y también reciben ordenes por el mismo medio. Eso funciona 100% por meses.
Trate de trabajar con el código, pero tienes entremezclado el MQTT con accesos a un servidor HTTP y ya se me hizo difícil tratar de modificarlo para poder probar solo el MQTT. Te recomiendo refactorizar para que el MQTT y HTTP sean independientes entre si.
Observo, pero no puedo comprabar que sea la causa del error que nunca haces un mqtt.connect(), lo que debes corregir.
Tome el ejemplo que viene con PubSubClient (mqtt basic), lo arregle para mi red y funciona más o menos. Tienes problemas, pero logra conectarse, enviar y recibir. Me suena a algún problema con la librería, ya que mientras tanto, mi MQTT sigue procesando los mensajes de mis otros controladores.
Este es el ejemplo, arreglado para usar Wifi
/*
 Basic MQTT example

 This sketch demonstrates the basic capabilities of the library.
 It connects to an MQTT server then:
  - publishes "hello world" to the topic "outTopic"
  - subscribes to the topic "inTopic", printing out any messages
    it receives. NB - it assumes the received payloads are strings not binary

 It will reconnect to the server if the connection is lost using a blocking
 reconnect function. See the 'mqtt_reconnect_nonblocking' example for how to
 achieve the same result without blocking the main loop.
 
*/
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// Update these with values suitable for your network.
#define WiFi_SSID "ChaosManor"
#define WiFi_PASS "belalugosi"

IPAddress server(192, 168, 0, 1);

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}


WiFiClient wifiClient;
PubSubClient client(wifiClient);

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect("arduinoClient")) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      client.publish("outTopic","hello world");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("inTopic");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(15000);
    }
  }
}

void setupWifi() {
  delay(10);

  // Nos conectamos al wifi
  Serial.println("WiFi Setup");
  Serial.print("Conectando a SSID: ");
  Serial.print(WiFi_SSID);

  WiFi.begin(WiFi_SSID, WiFi_PASS);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Conectado a red WiFI!!!");
  Serial.print("Direccion Ip: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  setupWifi();
  client.setServer(server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);

  // Allow the hardware to sort itself out
  delay(1500);
}

void loop()
{
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();
}

Produce
17:42:08.536 -> WiFi Setup
17:42:08.536 -> Conectando a SSID: ChaosManor.
17:42:09.115 -> Conectado a red WiFI!!!
17:51:27.663 -> Direccion Ip: 192.168.0.197
17:51:29.139 -> Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
17:51:47.149 -> Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
17:52:05.165 -> Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
17:52:23.154 -> Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
17:52:41.175 -> Attempting MQTT connection...connected
17:53:46.668 -> Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
17:53:54.669 -> Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
17:54:02.675 -> Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
17:54:10.677 -> Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
17:54:18.679 -> Attempting MQTT connection...connected
17:54:23.306 -> Message arrived [inTopic] Candid Moe
17:54:38.447 -> Message arrived [inTopic] Candid Moe 2
17:54:52.938 -> Message arrived [inTopic] Candid Moe 3
17:54:52.938 -> Message arrived [inTopic] Candid Moe 3

Como vez, envia mensajes y también los recibe, con un montón de desconexiones entre medio.

Candid Moe Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta!!! El problema ya esta soluciondo era un simple delay que no puse. En segundo lugar a que te refieres con que el mqtt y el http estan entremezclados, si te refieres a la funcion setup_miner() donde se mezcla el http con el mqtt eso es justamente por una cuestion de seguridad, yo recupero las credenciales del mqtt de un servidor, protegido previamente por usuario y contraseña para prevenir posibles filtraciones de credenciales/datos.
En tercer lugar yo primero programe el minero y luego le agrege el mqtt por encima, como una capa de telemetria.

El problema ya esta sulucionado, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!!!

@joaquinStrada Mezclar códigos no los hace más seguro. Los hace más confuso, complicado, difícil de mantener y depurar. Es más factible que introduzcas errores y debilidades que puedan ser explotadas por terceros.

enrtonces como se deberia hacer??? debo poner las credenciales en el codigo o a que te referis????

Tienes una función que inicializa el monedero y que obtiene las datos del MQTT. Tienes una segunda función que inicializa el MQTT recibiendo servidor, puerta, etc. Desde el setup() primero llamas a una y luego llamas a la otra. Son las mismas instrucciones que ya tienes, que se ejecutan en casi la misma secuencia, sólo que están físicamente separadas en el código fuente. Para el computador da lo mismo, pero a ti, como programador, te será más claro.

Y si eso es lo que hago en setup_miner() recivo los datos de configuracion del minero, del mqtt y los mando a clases fisicamente separadas para la configuracion de ambos, no te entiendo??? PD: Leiste el codigo???

Si, lo lei, lo estudie. Sigue adelante con tu vida.

Tampoco te ofendas, es que me parece que me decis que haga justamente lo que estoy haciendo.
